# tflearn mismatch tensor shape

Tags: image, preloader, tflearn

Odd error. I was using color images and everything was working. Now to save time and speed process I decided to work with gray images with just one dimension (before it was 4). The code is very much the same as before with a few changes. But now I get an error saying the shape is not the same. Any help ?

X, Y = image_preloader(dataset_file, image_shape=(704,800), mode="file", categoriacal_labels=True, normalize=True, files_extension="jpeg", gray_scale=True)

network = input_data(shape=[None, 704, 800, 1])

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (128, 704, 800) for Tensor 'InputData/X:0', which has shape '(?, 704, 800, 1)'

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old, but hopefully it helps you or someone else.

Your grayscale images no longer have multiple dimensions for RGB data/channels, so you have to reflect this in the input_data shape parameter by changing it to:

```
network = input_data(shape=[None, 704, 800])
```